# automake: how to portably throw an error and aborting the target

Tags: makefile, autotools, autoconf, automake

Depending on a condition checked for in the configure script, I want to throw an error, thus aborting the target. (i.e. refuse to compile tests on 'make check', if the test framework is not installed)

The behavior I want to achieve is, that when you call `make check`, it will directly print diagnostics and exits.

However, if the Makefile contains:

```
# if check is missing, don't do anything at all
if MISSING_CHECK
check:
    @echo "tests are disabled due to missing check"
    $(error tests are disabled due to missing check)

endif
```

Automake answers this:

```
automake-1.16: warnings are treated as errors
Makefile.am:9: warning: error tests are disabled due to missing check: non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.am:9: (probably a GNU make extension)
make: *** [Makefile:347: ../Makefile.in] Error 1
```

So the question is, how I could portably can throw an error.

---

Thanks to @John Bollinger /Makefile.am now looks like this:

```
## Process this file with automake to produce Makefile.in

SUBDIRS = . src tests

# if check is missing, don't do anything at all
if MISSING_CHECK
check:
    @echo "tests are disabled due to missing check"
    @exit 1

endif

ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = --install -I build-macro
```

And in /configure.ac there is:

```
AM_CONDITIONAL([MISSING_CHECK], [test x${enable_tests} = xno])
```

where enable_tests is either set to yes or no.

/tests/Makefile.am contains this:

```
# Process this file with automake to produce Makefile.in

AM_CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra $(CHECK_CFLAGS)

TESTS =
TESTS += test_integer

check_PROGRAMS = $(TESTS)
[...]
```

If I execute `make check`, it currently looks like this:

```
Making check in .
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/build'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'check-am'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/build'
Making check in src
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/build/src'
Making check in lib
make[2]: Entering directory '/tmp/build/src/lib'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'check'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/build/src/lib'
make[2]: Entering directory '/tmp/build/src'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/build/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/build/src'
Making check in tests
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/build/tests'
make  
make[2]: Entering directory '/tmp/build/tests'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/build/tests'
make  check-TESTS
make[2]: Entering directory '/tmp/build/tests'
make[3]: Entering directory '/tmp/build/tests'
============================================================================
Testsuite summary for libvector 0.9
============================================================================
# TOTAL: 0
# PASS:  0
# SKIP:  0
# XFAIL: 0
# FAIL:  0
# XPASS: 0
# ERROR: 0
============================================================================
make[3]: Leaving directory '/tmp/build/tests'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/build/tests'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/build/tests'
tests are disabled due to missing check
make: *** [Makefile:820: check] Error 1
```

Which seams to tell a user, that all tests have succeed. But I want the error to be thrown before the Testsuite is tried to run.

**Chosen solution**

As it turned out, that overwriting the test-harness is quite difficult, because it is unconditionally added before any custom rules and to do so you have to depend on implementation defined characteristics of automake. See John Bollinger's answer for more details.

That's why instead of overwriting the test harness, I add only a single shell script to it, in case the tests aren't to be compiled.
/tests/Makefile.am:

```
# if check is missing, run script to inform the user of this
if MISSING_CHECK
check_SCRIPTS = no_test.sh
# allow the script to echo to stderr
AM_TESTS_FD_REDIRECT = 9>&2
endif

if !MISSING_CHECK
check_PROGRAMS =
check_PROGRAMS += test_integer

endif

TESTS = $(check_SCRIPTS) $(check_PROGRAMS)
```

The script is generated by:
/configure.ac:

```
AC_CONFIG_FILES([tests/no_test.sh], [chmod +x tests/no_test.sh])
```

from:
/tests/no_test.sh.in:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Inform the user that tests are disabled and how to change that.
echo "No tests created due to missing check or user preference." >&2;
echo "No tests created due to missing check or user preference." >&9;
echo "To enable tests, run configure with --enable-tests=yes" >&2;
echo "To enable tests, run configure with --enable-tests=yes" >&9;
exit 1
```

Note that the user notification is issued twice as the stderr/stdout of the script is redirected to logfiles by the parallel test harness. &9 is then redirected to the real stderr by `AM_TESTS_FD_REDIRECT = 9>&2`. For the serial test harness it is simply directedto the real stderr and `AM_TESTS_FD_REDIRECT` is just ignored.
See: https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Testsuite-Environment-Overrides.html

The toplevel /Makefile.am is not changed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Autotools have a strong focus on portability across UNIX-like systems.  You can fight that in various ways, but then the question arises of why you are using the Autotools in the first place.

However, Automake has better ability to analyze your `Makefile.am` with respect to portability than Autoconf has to analyze your `configure.ac` in the same light.  If you write custom rules into your `Makefile.am` (or into another file that it `include`s) then you should stick to portable features, which mostly means those covered by the POSIX specifications for `make`.  GNU extensions are largely out, especially all the `make` "functions" it provides, such as `$(error)`.

> how I could portably can throw an error.

Generally speaking, in `make` recipes you should focus on *shell* features.  In this case, unless you employ the `make` syntax to specify otherwise, a recipe will fail, causing `make` to stop and report an error, if any of the commands in it fails.  There is a standard command whose entire purpose is to fail: `false`.  Alternatively, `exit 1` will terminate the shell with a failing exit status, which would serve the same purpose in this case.  Thus, you might do something like this:

```
# if check is missing, don't do anything at all
if MISSING_REQUIREMENTS
foo:
        @echo "optional component foo cannot be built due to missing requirements"
        @exit 1

endif
```

Alternatively, you could consider whether it would be sufficient to just print the diagnostic message, without failing.

---

**HOWEVER**, what you actually want to do is alter the behavior of a target (`check`) that belongs to Automake.  [This is allowed](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Not-Enough), but somewhat fraught.  In particular, the documentation remarks that

> Overriding Automake rules is often inadvisable, particularly in the topmost directory of a package with subdirectories.

You have exercised exactly the least-advisable case for overriding Automake rules, and "inadvisable" here manifests as "it won't have the result that you probably expect".

If you dig into the Makefile generated by `configure`, you will discover that the behavior you observe results from the fact that the top-level `check` target has a prerequisite (`check-recursive`) that implements the recursion.  The prerequisite is built before the override recipe for target `check` is executed.

In a recursive Automake makefile, the local, non-recursive version of each standard target is named with an `-am` suffix.  You can in fact see in your output that `check-am` in the top directory is the first target built when you `make check`.

Armed with that knowledge, you could obtain the behavior you are after by overriding `check-am` instead of `check`:

```
SUBDIRS = . src tests

# if check is missing, don't do anything at all
if MISSING_CHECK
check-am:
    @echo "tests are disabled due to missing check"
    @exit 1

endif
```

But note that

1. To get the result you want this way, you have to process the top-level directory first, which often conflicts with what you want for other purposes.
2. We are now depending on undocumented Automake implementation details.
3. Generally speaking, it is supported to run `make` in any of the subdirectories, and doing so will bypass any overrides or error generation implemented at the top level.

**Overall, my recommendation is *don't do that***.

DO have `configure` emit a warning if libcheck is not available (`AM_COND_IF` can help with that).  This is the best and most timely way to notify a builder of the issue.

DO suppress definition of any test cases when `CHECK_MISSING` is true, so that you don't hit builders with weird build failures in the event that they try a `make check` despite the warning from `configure`.

Possibly do even override the top-level `check` target to emit an explanatory message about the absence of test cases, maybe something more prominent, such as:

```
if MISSING_CHECK
check:
    @echo ============================================================================
    @echo "NOTICE: no test cases are available because libcheck is not installed"
    @echo ============================================================================

endif
```

And if you feel you must, do cause `make check` to fail in this case, by the means already described.

But DO NOT sweat the fact that an empty test suite is executed and summarized if a builder executes a `make check` despite having already been notified that no tests are available.

Comment: Thanks. While this answers my question, how I did ask it, I am wondering how I could stop make from further executing rules for a target, by throwing an error.
As I am new to asking questions on SO, I don't whether I should edit the question or ask a new one instead?

Comment: @caulder, what do you mean by "throwing an error" that is different from the effect this will produce?

Comment: This approach returns with an error, but still prints the test summary. I don't really understand this behavior, as it seams to be, that my rule is executed after the subdirectories, despite having SUBDIRS = . src tests

Comment: Ok, @caulder, the problem is that the title of your question is generic, but what you actually want to know requires an answer tailored to a special case.  I might have recognized that sooner if I were paying closer attention.  I'll respond further, possibly with a second answer.

Comment: @caulder, I decided against a separate answer.  I have updated this one with a response to your `make check` special case.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Based on your advice I have chosen a slightly different approach. I added it to my question. I hope that it will be more portable and keeping user-expected behavior, while still informing the user of the problem/their choice.

Comment: Messing with automake internal `foo-am` targets makes me uneasy when there is an explictly documented way to add your own make recipe to be run upon `make check`: According to https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Extending, you would add a `check-local` target with your extra make recipe. Whether that recipe running `exit 1` makes sense ore not, is a different question.

Comment: @ndim, I brought up `check-am` to explain what was happening and to provide an answer to the question as written.  I also recommended "don't do that", and cited reliance on implementation details among my reasons.  As for `check-local`, the problem with using it for the OP's purpose is that it is explicitly undocumented when a `check-local` rule will run relative to other rules triggered by a `make check`.  The question is not just about adding custom behavior; it's about getting that to run at the right time (though I do ultimately suggest abandoning that idea).